# Get frequency of words using Vocab in pytorch Torchtext

Tags: pytorch, torchtext

how can i get the frequencies of tokens in a torchtext vocab that is created using build_vocab_from_iterator? link to doc:https://pytorch.org/text/stable/vocab.html#torchtext.vocab.Vocab

```
def build_vocab(data_iter, tokenizer):
"""Builds vocabulary from iterator"""

    vocab = build_vocab_from_iterator(
            map(tokenizer, data_iter),
            specials=["<unk>"],
            min_freq=MIN_WORD_FREQUENCY,)
    vocab.set_default_index(vocab["<unk>"])
    return vocab

data_iter = get_data_iterator(ds_name, ds_type, data_dir)
tokenizer = get_english_tokenizer()

if not vocab:
    vocab = build_vocab(data_iter, tokenizer)
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get the frequency *after* you have built the vocab, since that data is lost during the build. It is just checking that the token occurs more than `min_freq`, and if so, adds it to the vocabulary.

However, you can get the frequency of the tokens *before* you build the vocabulary. One way to do that is with a `Counter` ([Counter docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)):

```
counter = Counter()
for text in data_iter:
    counter.update(tokenizer(text))
```

You can get the frequency of the tokens from the counter, then build the vocabulary from the counter:

```
vocab = vocab.vocab(counter, min_freq=MIN_WORD_FREQUENCY)
```